# Get messages and contacts from Linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api

I would like to do some analytics on my Linkedin account.
I would like to get a list of my messages and my contacts.

Is there an API for this, or is there any other way to get them - export or something....

Answer (score 1):

Contacts API provides a complete list of the authenticated user's address book on LinkedIn[here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v1/people/contacts-api)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if LinkedIn allow the enumeration of ones messages. However, sending, deleting, archiving messages are possible.

LinkedIn Messages API:
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v1/communications/message-api-calls

LinkedIn Contacts API:
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v1/people/contacts-api

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v1/contacts
```